# Drools Workbench 6.2 setup

Tags: installation, drools, workbench

I am doing POC for our client, and stuck with incomplete documentation.
while I created rule and Data Object, while i saved and built the rule project I can see the jar got created at maven path. so I tried look up this from my reader project.
using following code.

```
ReleaseId relesase = ks.newReleaseId( "myGroupID.MyArtifactID", "MyArtifactID", "1.0");

GroupId : myGroup1 
artifact ID :MyArtifactID
```

I already test this syntax with java based example, but cant use above for workbench created artifact.

Please help to know if i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You probably didn't put the workbench's maven repository in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`, like below. The KIE scanner / [Eclipse aether](http://www.eclipse.org/aether/) does not seem to use repositories defined in the `pom.xml`.

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>drools-maven</id>
      <username>yourusername</username>
      <password>yourpassword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>drools-maven</id>
          <name>Drools Maven Repository</name>
          <url>http://yourdomain.tld/drools/maven2</url>

          <!-- Include these to always update the repository -->
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I agree I think a lot of documentation is quite lacking. I think things are written as "It's possible to do this!" instead of "These are the steps necessary to do this".